# Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:10000

Tags: node.js, configuration, npm, hive

When I am trying to connect my node.js application to hive using node-thrift module it is giving me this error. My application's port no is 3000 and hive's port number is 10,000

```
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:10000
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:873:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:896:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1077:14)

npm ERR! Linux 3.19.0-64-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v4.4.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.8
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! testproj1@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the testproj1@0.0.0 start script 'node ./bin/www'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the testproj1 package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node ./bin/www
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs testproj1
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR! 
npm ERR!     npm owner ls testproj1
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/hduser/rproj/testproj1/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Did you check (e.g. via `netstat -nlp`) that the server is actually running?

Comment: netstat -a | grep 10000 nothing comes up even my hive is on

Comment: Thank you its working now :)